# Why is clang unwilling or unable to eliminate duplicate loads here

Tags: c, optimization, clang, llvm, strict-aliasing

Consider the following C program:

```c
typedef struct { int x; } Foo;

void original(Foo***** xs, Foo* foo) {
    xs[0][1][2][3] = foo;
    xs[0][1][2][3]->x = 42;
}
```

As far as I understand, per the C standard `Foo**` cannot alias `Foo*` etc, as their types are not compatible. Compiling the program with clang 14.0 and `-O3` however results in duplicate loads:

```
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 16]
    mov     qword ptr [rax + 24], rsi
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 16]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 24]
    mov     dword ptr [rax], 42
    ret
```

I would expect an optimising compiler to either:

**(A)** Assign to `x` on `foo` directly and assign `foo` to `xs` (in any order)
**(B)** Perform address calculations for `xs` once and use them for assigning `foo` and `x`.

Clang correctly compiles **B**:

```c
void fixed(Foo***** xs, Foo* foo) {
    Foo** ix = &xs[0][1][2][3];
    *ix = foo;
    (*ix)->x = 42;
}
```

as follows: (actually turning it into **A**)

```
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 16]
    mov     qword ptr [rax + 24], rsi
    mov     dword ptr [rsi], 42
    ret
```

Interestingly gcc compiles both definitions into **A**. Why is clang unwilling or unable to optimise the address calculation in the `original` definition?

[Compiler Explorer Playground](https://godbolt.org/z/x6cqzG5vq)

Comment: If gcc does the optimization, then the most likely explanation is that the optimization is legal and clang simply misses it.

Comment: I'm working on a toy compiler and I'm really curious why clang/llvm misses it. At LLVM IR level the transformation looks quite simple and in my real code the 2nd argument `foo` doesn't exist - instead I use malloc so I know it's `noalias` (I removed malloc for the question since it made no difference).

Comment: @NateEldredge: Note that a quality compiler should hold off on trying to make optimizations until they can be proven sound in all cases.  While it's easy to make toy examples where optimizations can be proven sound, most simple rules to identify cases where optimizations can be proven sound wouldn't be applicable in enough *real-world* code to be worthwhile.

Comment: @supercat I think the optimisation is 'sound' according to the C spec and Nate is correct. It also seems like LLVM devs think stricter analysis could make a difference. The problem of course is how easy it is to accidentally violate C's aliasing model.

Comment: @MaciejGoszczycki: The analysis may be sound when operations are expressed as shown in source code, but before performing an optimization a quality compiler must also ensure that the same sequence of operations *could not be generated by earlier optimization passes which were fed code where the optimization would not be sound*.  Rather than working on trying to optimize obscure cases, efforts would be better spent figuring out a better abstraction model that ensures that code doesn't get transformed by one pass into code which another pass then treats as invoking UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be it's an open LLVM issue: [[TBAA] Emit distinct TBAA tags for pointers with different depths,types.](https://reviews.llvm.org/D122573)

Jérôme's answer tipped me off that this might have something to do with Type Based Alias Analysis (TBAA) when I noticed all loads use the same TBAA metadata.

Right now clang only emits<sup>*</sup> the following TBAA:

```
; Descriptors
!15 = !{!"Simple C/C++ TBAA"}
!14 = !{!"omnipotent char", !15, i64 0}
!13 = !{!"any pointer", !14, i64 0}
!21 = !{!"int", !14, i64 0}
!20 = !{!"", !21, i64 0}
; Tags
!12 = !{!13, !13, i64 0}
!19 = !{!20, !21, i64 0}
```

Looking at the LLVM revision I figured eventually clang might be able to emit something along the lines of:

```
; Type descriptors
!0 = !{!"TBAA Root"}
!1 = !{!"omnipotent char", !0, i64 0}
!3 = !{!"int", !0, i64 0}
!2 = !{!"any pointer", !1, i64 0}
!11 = !{!"p1 foo", !2, i64 0} ; Foo*
!12 = !{!"p2 foo", !2, i64 0} ; Foo**
!13 = !{!"p3 foo", !2, i64 0} ; Foo***
!14 = !{!"p4 foo", !2, i64 0} ; Foo****
!10 = !{!"foo", !3, i64 0} ; struct {int x}

; Access tags
!20 = !{!14, !14, i64 0} ; Foo****
!21 = !{!13, !13, i64 0} ; Foo***
!22 = !{!12, !12, i64 0} ; Foo**
!23 = !{!11, !11, i64 0} ; Foo*
!24 = !{!10, !3, i64 0}  ; Foo.x
```

(I'm still not sure I fully grok the TBAA metadata format so please excuse any mistakes)

Together with the code below LLVM produces the expected assembly.

```
define void @original(ptr %0, ptr %1) {
  %3 = load ptr, ptr %0, !tbaa !20
  %4 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %3, i64 1
  %5 = load ptr, ptr %4, !tbaa !21
  %6 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %5, i64 2
  %7 = load ptr, ptr %6, !tbaa !22
  %8 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %7, i64 3
  store ptr %1, ptr %8, !tbaa !23

  %9 = load ptr, ptr %0, !tbaa !20
  %10 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %9, i64 1
  %11 = load ptr, ptr %10, !tbaa !21
  %12 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %11, i64 2
  %13 = load ptr, ptr %12, !tbaa !22
  %14 = getelementptr ptr, ptr %13, i64 3
  %15 = load ptr, ptr %14, !tbaa !23 ; : Foo*
  store i32 42, ptr %15, !tbaa !24

  ret void
}
```

[Compiler Explorer Playground](https://godbolt.org/z/sx8Kqee9K)

* Compiler's Explorer LLVM IR view filters these out by default but you can see them by using `-emit-llvm` and disabling "Directives" filtering

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer.

The loads are performed twice because the optimizer missed the optimization. It succeed to detect this specific case, but fail by reporting the following errors:

> Missed - load of type ptr not eliminated in favor of load because it is clobbered by store 
> Missed - load of type ptr not eliminated because it is clobbered by store 
> Missed - load of type ptr not eliminated because it is clobbered by store 
> Missed - load of type ptr not eliminated because it is clobbered by store

You can see that by opening the "optimization output" window in Godbolt.

This optimization is performed by the Global Value Numbering (GVN) pass in LLVM and the specific error appears to be reported from the function [`reportMayClobberedLoad`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/GVN_8cpp_source.html#l01042). The code states that the missed load-elimination is due to an intervening store (again). For more information, one certainly need to delve into the algorithm of this optimization pass. A good start seems to be the [`GVNPass::AnalyzeLoadAvailability`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/GVN_8cpp_source.html#l01137) function. Fortunately, the code is commented.

Note a simplified `Foo**` use-case is optimized and a simplified `Foo***` use-case is not optimized by default, but using `restrict` fix the missed-optimization (it looks like the optimizer wrongly assumes that aliasing can be an issue here due to the store).

I am wondering if this could be due to the LLVM-IR which seems to make no distinction between a `Foo**` or `Foo***` pointer types: they are apparently all considered as raw pointers. Thus, the store forwarding optimization could fail because of the store may impact any pointer of the chain and the optimizer cannot know which one due to the aliasing (itself due to the loss of pointer type). Here is the produced LLVM-IR code:

```
define dso_local void @original(ptr nocapture noundef readonly %0, ptr noundef %1) local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !9 {
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata ptr %0, metadata !24, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !26
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata ptr %1, metadata !25, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !26
  %3 = load ptr, ptr %0, align 8, !dbg !27, !tbaa !28
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %3, i64 1, !dbg !27
  %5 = load ptr, ptr %4, align 8, !dbg !27, !tbaa !28
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %5, i64 2, !dbg !27
  %7 = load ptr, ptr %6, align 8, !dbg !27, !tbaa !28
  %8 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %7, i64 3, !dbg !27
  store ptr %1, ptr %8, align 8, !dbg !32, !tbaa !28
  %9 = load ptr, ptr %0, align 8, !dbg !33, !tbaa !28
  %10 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %9, i64 1, !dbg !33
  %11 = load ptr, ptr %10, align 8, !dbg !33, !tbaa !28
  %12 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %11, i64 2, !dbg !33
  %13 = load ptr, ptr %12, align 8, !dbg !33, !tbaa !28
  %14 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %13, i64 3, !dbg !33
  %15 = load ptr, ptr %14, align 8, !dbg !33, !tbaa !28
  store i32 42, ptr %15, align 4, !dbg !34, !tbaa !35
  ret void, !dbg !38
}
```